# LIFO memory vhdl code understanding

Tags: vhdl, lifo

I have this code for a lifo memory and I don't understand why on 27 line (if(last = n-2) then full <= '1'; end if;) the **last** signal it's not equal to n-1.
If anyone could explain it to me I would really appreciate.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity lifo is
  generic(n : natural := 4);
  port(Din         : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
       Dout        : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
       wr          : in  std_logic;
       rd          : in  std_logic;
       empty, full : out std_logic;
       clk         : in  std_logic);
end entity lifo;

architecture arh of lifo is
  type memorie is array(0 to n-1) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal mem  : memorie := (others => (others => '0'));
  signal last : integer range -1 to n-1;
begin
  process(clk)
  begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) and (wr = '1') then
      if (last = n-1) then null;
      else
        if(last = n-2) then full <= '1'; end if;
        if(last = -1) then empty <= '0'; end if;
        mem(last + 1)            <= Din;
        last                     <= last + 1;
      end if;
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) and (rd = '1') then
      if(last = -1) then null;
      else
        Dout                     <= mem(last);
        last                     <= last - 1; full <= '0';
        if(last = -1) then empty <= '1'; end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
end architecture arh;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `last` is in `range -1 to n-1`, and when `last` is n-1 then it indicates full LIFO, and `full` must be high (`'1'`).

When a write is accepted, then `last` is incremented by 1 with `last <= last + 1`. On the same rising `clk` edge it is determined if `full` should go high, which is the case if this write will make the LIFO full. After the write, then `last` has the value last+1 (the +1 when write is accepted) and LIFO is full if is equals n-1 (with n-1 indicating full).  So the condition for full after this write is last+1=n-1, which is then written as `last = n-2`.

In addition, it is possible to improve the code in several ways if it does not work right away, e.g. single `rising_edge(clk)`, add reset, skip the `null` statements through negated condition, add handling of write and read operation in same cycle, remove dead code (the final `if`).